# Extracting specific string in a url using java code/javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the below url and I need to get back the value after api/ which is nam.

http://apidtgateway.mycompany.co.za:9800/agencychannel-uiapiservices/api/nam/CrmUserManagement/SaveActivity

Any help would be highly appriciated thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Choose a language. 2. look at "split" or similar method

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely different languages. The name shouldn't confuse you.

Comment: I would use a `Regex` here to get the value directly. But choose your language first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you will do it.

```js
var URL = "http://apidtgateway.mycompany.co.za:9800/agencychannel-uiapiservices/api/nam/CrmUserManagement/SaveActivity";
if (URL.indexOf("api/") >= 0) {
  var part = URL.split("api/")[1].split("/")[0];
  console.log(part);
}
```

Comment: Like I said, I would use a regex here, to get only the value between `"api/"` and the next  `"/"`. Two split seems a bit expensive